# Converting RA and DEC to cartessian coordinate system

Tags: trigonometry

I have the Right Ascension in decimal hours and declination in degrees. How can I get the cartesian coordinate of a star without concern for it's distance.

Comment: Do you want to transform RA and DEC into ALT AZ coordinates?

Comment: No I want to convert them to xz. I don't need the y vertical coordinate.

Comment: You have to decide the orientation of your $xy$ reference frame

Comment: What choices are there for the xy reference frame? The way I'm doing it now is in a 3D program like

Comment: AR and Dec refers to an 'equatorial' reference frame. So you have the plane $xy$ coincident to the plane defined by the equatorial projection on the sky. You can fix the $x$ axis coincident to the $\gamma$ point (intersection of celestial equator and ecliptic). Obviuusly you have also the $z$ axis defined by the $Dec$. So, you can transform $RA$ and $Dec$ in $Alt$ and $Az$ otherwise you need in any case $xyz$

Comment: Was trying to edit my comment above but it doesn't let me. Here is the rest of what I was saying:
The way I'm doing it now is in a 3D program. I center a circle over 0,0 and make the radius equal to the declination. Then I turn the circle using the RA. This positions the object that is on the circle at the correct xy coordinate. It's a very manual process so was hoping to use excel to come up with the correct xy and then I can just import it.
The formula I use in excel for radius: 69×(90−(IF(-16.7="","",SIGN(-16.7)×(ABS(-16.7)))))
The I do this to with RA to set the other angle: 6.75÷24×360

Comment: BTW, in the program I'm using, z represents altitude so x and y is my ground coordinate that I'm trying to solve. In my example above I'm referring to the star Sirius and in my manual way of doing it, I came up with x = -1436.313 miles and y = 7220.835 miles which is exactly what I want.

Comment: This is not possible or I'm not explaining it correctly?